# VS Code and WSL Integrated Terminal - I cannot set WSL as my default terminal

Tags: windows, terminal, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After selecting WSL as my default terminal in Visual Studio code, I am unable to open up a terminal window. The terminal window opens, random text appears on the screen, and then the terminal closes with an error message that says: "The terminal process terminated with exit code: 4294967295".

Does anyone know why this is? I have looked at some of the vscode github issue posts, but I can't seem to make anything work.

See screenshot of my settings.json file and a gif of what is happening below:

[image: settings.json]

[image: gif of me trying to open a wsl integrated terminal]

Answer (score 4):

if you have a line in the settings.json file like this

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["--login", "-i"],
```

just remove it, or comment out this line to be like this

```
//"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["--login", "-i"],
```

Finally, change the terminal.integrated.shell.windows settings to be like this

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
```

Comment: I did not have the "login" line in my settings.json file. However, I added the shell line that you said to add, and it worked. It is weird though because I originally added this line, and it did not work. I recently wiped my computer and reinstalled everything. I must have had some setting that was breaking the funtionality. Or, I installed a newer version of VS Code that fixed my original problem. Thanks!

Comment: The "terminal.integrate.shell.windows" change fixed mine.

Comment: Everybody mentions about settings.json but I could not find this file where is settings.json?

Answer (score 3):

Answer updated for vs code 1.56.2.  I started seeing a warning in my Settings.json.
Here's how I managed to do this:

Settings.json:

```json
 "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "WSL",
 "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"            
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        },
        "WSL": {
            "path": [
                "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-ubuntu-wsl"
        }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

When try to open WSL from VSCode was getting error

*The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe" terminated with exit code: 4294967295.*

Similar error when tried to execute C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe from Windows Console (cmd.exe)

Did a WSL shutdown from Windows Console (**wsl --shutdown**) and got the popup below. Re-started Docker and could open WSL from VS Code.

[image: Docker restart]

Answer (score 0):

This problem might occur when you don't have Ubuntu or any other linux installed in system.

You can install Ubuntu through Microsoft store in Windows:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wM-wBciLeDw

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I do have WSL enabled and have Ubuntu installed. I think this is because of the way VS Code works with the subsystem. WSL works as my terminal if I open VS Code from within WSL. I do not think you can have WSL as the default terminal when opeing VS Code from the Windows side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Open your *settings.json* file and change the line to:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
```

Comment: I'm not looking to have cmd.exe as my shell. I want wsl. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, here is how i fix it

1. go to control panel -> Programs -> turn windows features on or off -> **check list Windows Subsytem for linux**
   [how to check list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBgh0.png)
2. next go to Microsoft Store search for **ubuntu** then install , i did get an error like you so i install **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**. now i have 2 types of ubuntu installed
3. lastly open cmd -> right click -> properties -> **then uncheck use legacy
   console** [how to uncheck use legacy console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkQEQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70035055/5078874

Instead of `terminal.integrated.shell.windows`.

Use setting like this: `"terminal.external.windowsExec": "wsl.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

On vscode 1.85.1, is working just by adding in my settings:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Ubuntu (WSL)",
```