# Why does my WSL in vscode terminate with exit code "4294967295"

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am accustomed to using WSL in my vscode to code with cpp.

Today I configured Go in my vscode and run it successfully in powershell cmd.

However, when I transfer to WSL, it was terminated with "4294967295". I searched for a lot of resources but cannot figure out how to solve it.

This is my settings.json file and snapshot in vscode. Can somebody help me? Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6nc4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUpFo.png)

Comment: Please don't include picture links; instead post the exact code from the pictures into your post with the code formatting for better legibility and so all information for the question is self-contained within the post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `terminal.integrated.shell.windows`, which is used for `cmd.exe` (in my case)

Use setting like this: `"terminal.external.windowsExec": "wsl.exe"`

Comment: where is the settings?

Comment: In Windows type `Ctrl+,`, then in Search type "terminal.external.windowsExec"

Answer (score -2):

Its probably beacuse your computer can find the VM, try this:

```
DISM /online /disable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /norestart
DISM /online /disable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /norestart
```

Reboot, and then:

```
DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /norestart
DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /norestart
```